# Openvpn two factor authentification problems after upgrade to 22.04

Tags: server, upgrade, vpn, openvpn

after upgrading from Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04 I got problems when connecting to
a server running on Ubuntu 22.04.
The server is running openvpn "OpenVPN 2.5.5" and the clients, all showing the
same problem, running either Ubuntu 22.04 (OpenVPN 2.5.5) or Ubuntu 20.04
(OpenVPN 2.4.7). The server is a plain Ubuntu 22.04 minimal server installation
and "apt install openvpn".

You will find the configurations at the end of the text (I know there are some old items but they
seem not to be the problem, since I change them while testing, too).

When I try to connect, it sometimes works but sometimes fails with an authentification error
(as you can see from the configs, we are using two factor authentification). About 7 out of 10 times
the connection works. the default configuration of openvpn does not try again when getting an
authentification error, this can be mitigated be using "auth-retry nointeract" in the clients
config, but still you can get "pauses" in you VPN connection. This can be further
mitigated by using reneg-sec 0 in client and server, but both messures do not resolve the
problem.

In the auth log of the server I get the following

> **** restart openvpn on client for testing
>
> Aug  4 07:48:49 openvpn-test01 openvpn[26669]: pam_userdb(openvpn:auth): user
> `client-xxxx' denied access (incorrect password) Aug  4 07:50:01
> openvpn-test01 openvpn[28663]: pam_userdb(openvpn:auth): user
> 'client-xxxx' granted access
>
> **** restart openvpn on client for testing
>
> Aug  4 07:51:50 openvpn-test01 openvpn[28663]: message repeated 4 times: [
> pam_userdb(openvpn:auth): user `client-xxxx' denied access (incorrect
> password)] Aug  4 07:52:01 openvpn-test01 openvpn[28663]:
> pam_userdb(openvpn:auth): user 'client-xxxx' granted access

In the client openvpn log I see (after the cert check went well):

> Thu Aug  4 09:46:02 2022 us=958577 AUTH: Received control message:
> AUTH_FAILED Thu Aug  4 09:46:02 2022 us=958860 TCP/UDP: Closing socket
> Thu Aug  4 09:46:02 2022 us=958936 SIGUSR1[soft,auth-failure]
> received, process restarting Thu Aug  4 09:46:02 2022 us=958986
> Restart pause, 10 second(s)

The server log (dont look at the timestamps, they are from different attempts):

> 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=384638 PLUGIN AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: received
> command code: 0 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=384739 PLUGIN AUTH-PAM:
> BACKGROUND: USER: client-xxx 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=389201 PLUGIN
> AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: my_conv[0] query='Password: ' style=1 2022-08-04
> 07:51:50 us=389604 PLUGIN AUTH-PAM: BACKGROUND: user 'client-xxx'
> failed to authenticate: Authentication failure 2022-08-04 07:51:50
> us=390537 192.168.123.10:33581 PLUGIN_CALL: POST
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so/PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY
> status=1 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=390599 192.168.123.10:33581
> PLUGIN_CALL: plugin function PLUGIN_AUTH_USER_PASS_VERIFY failed with
> status 1:
> /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so
> 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=390690 192.168.123.10:33581 TLS Auth Error:
> Auth Username/Password verification failed for peer 2022-08-04
> 07:51:50 us=391547 192.168.123.10:33581 Control Channel: TLSv1.3,
> cipher TLSv1.3 TLS_AES_256_GCM_SHA384, peer certificate: 4096 bit RSA,
> signature: RSA-SHA256 2022-08-04 07:51:50 us=391626
> 192.168.123.10:33581 [client-xxx] Peer Connection Initiated with [AF_INET]192.168.123.10:33581 2022-08-04 07:51:51 us=566578
> 192.168.123.10:33581 PUSH: Received control message: 'PUSH_REQUEST'

If the connect fails I also see this with tcpdump (openvpn-test01 being the server):

> 07:57:49.100580 IP 192.168.123.10 > openvpn-test01: ICMP
> 192.168.123.10 udp port 51174 unreachable, length 156

What I have tried so far:

1. Install openvpn 2.4 on Ubuntu 22.04 -> same behaviour
2. Adjust configuration (e.g. set "multihome") -> no success (and keep in mind it is perfectly working with 20.04 and most of the time with 22.04)
3. Debug the client to see what happens (with strace) -> as soon as strace is connected to the client I clould not reproduce the error (100 connects in a row without problem)

So i guess there is somehow a timing problem between the openvpn server and the pam module or the client.

Has anyone else the problem and is able to give me a hint whats going wrong here?

Thanks.

Best,

Jan

Server:

```
mode server
tls-server
port 1194 
proto udp 
dev tun_xxx
persist-key
persist-tun
ca [inline]
cert [inline]
key [inline]
dh [inline]
tls-auth [inline] 0
#tls-version-min 1.2
explicit-exit-notify 1
float
auth SHA512

cipher AES-256-CBC

crl-verify crl.pem
log /var/log/openvpn.log

client-config-dir ccd

topology subnet
push "topology subnet"
ifconfig 10.20.40.1 255.255.255.0
route 10.20.40.0 255.255.255.0 10.20.40.1 1
push "route 10.20.40.0 255.255.255.0 10.20.40.1 1"
comp-lzo

max-clients 254
user nobody                                                                                                                                                                                                                      
group nogroup                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
keepalive 10 60                                                                                                                                                                                                                 
status /var/log/openvpn-status.log                                                                                                                                                                                               
verb 4                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
chroot /opt/yyy/xxx/
reneg-sec 0
plugin /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/openvpn/plugins/openvpn-plugin-auth-pam.so openvpn
```

pam.d config:

```
auth   required    pam_userdb.so    crypt=crypt db=/opt/xxx/yyyy/zzzz-pw
account required      pam_permit.so
```

Client:

```
client
dev tun_xxx
proto udp
port 1194
remote xx.xx.xx.xx 
float
nobind
pull
persist-key
persist-tun
ca [inline]
cert [inline]
key [inline]
remote-cert-tls server
tls-auth [inline] 1
auth SHA512
cipher AES-256-CBC
log /var/log/openvpn.log
verb 4 
route-method exe
route-delay 2
auth-user-pass xxx.txt
auth-retry nointeract
comp-lzo
auth-nocache
```